# What does varying=list(2) mean in R's reshape tool?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am trying to learn a package in R, and one example required me to use the `reshape` function. I know the "varying" parameter in reshape is the vector/list of variable names. But the example shows `reshape(...varying=list(2))` - what does this exactly do? `list(2)` doesn't really give any info?

Comment: It should be the column index. i.e 2nd column in your dataframe

Comment: Wrong tag: you want to use [tag:data.frame]